# menu-bar-mode and tool-bar-mode change frame size

Tags: frames

Am calling the following two functions repeatedly (`toro-fullscreen` followed by  "toro-normal").  The size of the frame changes.  The problem happens when calling "menu-bar-mode" and "tool-bar-mode".  Calling just `(toggle-frame-fullscreen)` always brings frame size to its original dimensions.

```
(defun toro-fullscreen ()
  "Use fullscreen without tool bars."
  (interactive)
  (toggle-frame-fullscreen)
  (menu-bar-mode -1)
  (tool-bar-mode -1))

(defun toro-normal ()
  "Revert to original"
  (interactive)  
  (menu-bar-mode 1)
  (tool-bar-mode 1) 
  (toggle-frame-fullscreen))
```

Comment: What goes wrong with `toro-normal`?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: The frame keeps getting smaller and smaller the more I call `toro-fullscreen`, `toro-normal`.  Am unsure on the use of `'fullscreen` for `toro-normal`.  I want to get back to how everything was before calling`toro-fullscreen`.

Comment: In `toro-normal` you need `(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'fullscreen nil)` instead of what you currently have.

Comment: Still get the same problem.

Comment: Maybe looking at `toggle-frame-fullscreen` would be a good idea.

Comment: Done so, problem persists.

Comment: The problem is not because of `toggle-frame-fullscreen`, the problem is in doing  `(menu-bar-mode -1) (tool-bar-mode -1)`  then  `(menu-bar-mode 1) (tool-bar-mode 1)`, and so on.

Comment: Consider rewriting yr question to make all of this clear.